# how to pass json in python

Tags: python, json

I am using python and have a json response :

```
{u'outcomes': [{u'entities': {}, u'confidence': 0.951, u'intent': u'timeanddate', u'_text': u'what is the'}], u'msg_id': u'629bbdbd-788b-4418-a5cf-1f9a7895f490', u'_text': u'what is the'}
```

I would like to access the information like this or something similar:

```
COMMANDS["outcomes"]["intent"]
```

How would I do this.

Thank You

Comment: That's actually a python dictionary, not JSON

Comment: ...it may have been a JSON response **earlier**, but it's not JSON any more at the point in time when it's quoted for that question, which means that its history as JSON is effectively irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay attention to the hierarchy. You'll notice the dictionary containing the `intent` key is *nested* in a list, so you'll have to index the list before you can access the dictionary:

```
COMMANDS["outcomes"][0]["intent"]
#                    ^ --> dictionary is located at index 0 of the list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourString = {u'outcomes': [{u'entities': {}, u'confidence': 0.951, u'intent': u'timeanddate', u'_text': u'what is the'}], u'msg_id': u'629bbdbd-788b-4418-a5cf-1f9a7895f490', u'_text': u'what is the'}
yourString['outcomes'][0]['intent']
>>> u'timeanddate'
```